# Finding eigenvectors and eigenvalues of large matrices in Python's numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am running a PCA analysis on a data set using Python's (v2.7.10) NumPy.  I validated that my program works by running the PCA analysis on a smaller dataset and then confirming that I get similar results using `sklearn.decomposition`.

When I run my full dataset (with 60000 variables and 93 samples), I experience some strangeness.  After I construct my covariance matrix (which is 60000 x 60000), I compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors using `numpy.linalg.eig()`.  When I inspect the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, all the entries are exactly 0.

This leads me to believe that there is something strange with the behavior of `numpy.linalg.eig()` due to the large matrix size.

**QUESTION** : What is going on?  What assumptions are breaking down? How do I fix it?

Comment: Presumably the rank of the matrix is only 93, so all but the first 93 eigenvalues would be zero. You could instead compute the thin SVD of the thin $60000 \times 93$ matrix, and then square the singular values to get the eigenvalues of the $60000 \times 60000$ matrix.